# Указатель(тип)+ вопрос по стринг

Tags: golang

Синтаксис var p *int означает что сам указатель имеет тип int или то что он указывает на значение int ?
То есть могу ли я применить такой синтаксис var p *string ?

В Go string просто последовательность байт?

Answer (score 1):

> Синтаксис var p *int означает что сам указатель имеет тип int или то что он указывает на значение int?

Указатель на значение типа int.

> В Go string просто последовательность байт?

Не совсем. В го использутся не C-строки, а P-строки. То есть string - это структура типа

```
type string struct {
    len  int
    data *byte
}
```

Где len - длина строки, а data - указатель на первый байт.